# What is the architectural purpose of the "view state" in JSF?

Tags: jsf

What is the architectural purpose of the "view state" in JSF?

I understand that it stores the original state of the components on the page and is used during the JSF lifecycle when the FacesServlet receives a request. But why is it needed? What if the view state did not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *What if the view state did not exist?*

The view would then not be mutable from the server side on. For example, you won't be able to attach/remove an `UIComponent` programmatically.

It's however quite possible to make JSF entirely stateless. See also this [blog article](http://industrieit.com/blog/2011/11/stateless-jsf-high-performance-zero-per-request-memory-overhead/).

#### See also:

- [Why JSF saves the state of UI components on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474316/why-does-jsf-need-to-save-the-state-of-ui-components-on-the-server-side)

Comment: I also found your other post (which is linked to in the "Why does... server side?" page you reference) useful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349174/why-does-jsf-save-component-tree-state