# What is STATE_SAVING_METHOD parameter in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

I am not able to understand what is the function of this line in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have read that the NetBeans default is *client*. I've just faced an issue that I have many beans in my application, and the `<param-value>` was set to client, so I was getting

> java.io.NotSerializableException

error although my beans were Serializable (i.e. they implemented the Serializable interface.). My beans were in *@ViewScope*.  But when I changed it to server, things are going to work. Why? What is the difference when I use client and server. Can anyone explain me with the help of an example.

Thanks

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> ```
> java.io.NotSerializableException
> ```

This kind of exception has usually a message in the root cause which shows the fully qualified class name of the class which doesn't implement `Serializable`. You should pay close attention to this message to learn about which class it is talking about and then let it implement `Serializable` accordingly.

Often, making *only* your managed bean classes serializable is not always sufficient. You also need to ensure that **each of its properties** is also serializable. Most standard types like `String`, `Long`, etc implement all already `Serializable`. But (custom) complex types such as nested beans, entities or EJBs should each also be serializable. If something is not really implementable as `Serializable`, such as `InputStream`, then you should either redesign the model or make it `transient` (and keep in mind that it will be `null` after deserialization).

---

> *What is the difference when i use client and server*

First some background information: [Why JSF saves the state of UI components on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474316/why-does-jsf-need-to-save-the-state-of-ui-components-on-the-server-side)

The main technical difference is that the `client` setting stores the entire view state as the value of the `javax.faces.ViewState` hidden input field in the generated HTML output and that the `server` setting stores it in the session along with an unique ID which is in turn referenced as the value of the `javax.faces.ViewState` hidden input field.

So, setting to `client` increases the network bandwidth usage but decreases the server memory usage and setting to `server` does the other way round. Setting to `client` has however an additional functional advantage: it prevents `ViewExpiredException`s when the session has expired or when the client opens too many views.

Comment: What about CSRF and Phishing if I use client setting.

Comment: It's encrypted/enctyptable.

Answer (score 13):

`javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` parameter is used to specify where the state should be saved.

If you want to save the state on the server (which is the default in the JavaServer Faces reference implementation), specify the `param-value` value as `server`.

Otherwise to save the state on the client side we can specify `client` in the `param-value`.

If the state is saved on the client, the state of the entire view is rendered to a hidden field on the page.

Comment: Do not save serialized ViewState on the client side due to this bug http://foxglovesecurity.com/2015/11/06/what-do-weblogic-websphere-jboss-jenkins-opennms-and-your-application-have-in-common-this-vulnerability/