# JSF 2 Navigation with redirect rebuilds ViewScope page that uses ui:repeat

Tags: jsf-2

The situation is that I have a ViewScoped page that uses ui:repeat for laying out some components. I also on this page have some h:commandLinks that have action method specified. The action method performs some conditional logic to determine what navigation outcome to return. Upon returning an outcome and including "faces-redirect=true" to perform a redirect, the current view's bean is reinstantiated before the redirect occurs.

Removing the ui:repeat causes the issue to stop, I know longer see the constructor of the bean being invoked. Also, I cannot use h:links in this case, because I want to be able to calculate the outcome at the moment the link is clicked.

Is this a known bug with ui:repeat? I have searched around and could not find why this is happening.

Here is some sample code that I can reproduce this with using Mojarra JSF 2.1.6:

**example.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputText value="Bean property value: #{exampleBean.property}"/>
    <ui:repeat value="#{exampleBean.list}" var="item">
        <h:outputText value="#{item}"/>
    </ui:repeat>
    <br/><h:commandLink value="Action" action="#{exampleBean.someAction()}"/>
    <br/><h:commandLink value="Action w/Redirect" action="#{exampleBean.someRedirectAction()}"/>
</h:form>
```

**ExampleBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="exampleBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ExampleBean {

    private String property;
    private List<String> list;

    public ExampleBean() {
        System.err.println("Constructor invoked");
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("list item 1");
        list.add("list item 2");
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public String someAction() {
        System.err.println("someAction() invoked");
        if (calculateSomeCondition()) {
            return "otherView1";
        } else {
            return "otherView2";
        }
    }

    public String someRedirectAction() {
        System.err.println("someRedirectAction() invoked");
        if (calculateSomeCondition()) {
            return "otherView1?faces-redirect=true";
        } else {
            return "otherView2?faces-redirect=true";
        }
    }

    private boolean calculateSomeCondition() {
        // some logic to calc true/false
    }
}
```

Note that otherView1.xhtml and otherView2.xhtml are simple files sitting in the same directory as example.xhtml.

The output seen in the log upon loading the page and clicking the "Action" link:

*Constructor invoked*

*someAction() invoked*

The output seen in the log upon loading the page and clicking the "Action w/Redirect" link:

*Constructor invoked*

*someRedirectAction() invoked*

*Constructor invoked*

Comment: You're right, there seems to be no one specific problem with `<ui:repeat/>` and `@ViewScoped`. Setting the [state saving method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8471551/1530938) to server generally seems to resolve the bulk of the problems

Comment: My state saving method is set to server currently, I do not believe that is the cause of this problem.