# Advantage and disadvantage save state in Restore View in client/server JSF 2

Tags: jsf, client, phase

In the Restore View phase of JSF 2, we can config saving state of each components in server or client by

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have a question that what is advantage and disadvantage if we save the state in client or server side?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you must read

- [Why does JSF need to save the state of UI components on the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474316/why-does-jsf-need-to-save-the-state-of-ui-components-on-the-server-side)
- [What is STATE_SAVING_METHOD parameter in JSF 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471551/what-is-state-saving-method-parameter-in-jsf-2-0)

To summarize answer to your question,

**Client side:**
Saving state on the client results in less of a load on the server at the expense of 
additional network traffic. This is because by default, client side is stored as a large hidden 
`<input>` field in web browsers. Saving state on the client also works better in failover
situations because even if the server is down, the state won't be lost.

State saving at client side is having security concerns as well as overhead of serialization of entire JSF tree every time.

**Server side:**
Prevents [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and [phishing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing) attacks.

Comment: CSRF isn't really a big issue in JSF; state saved on the client is encrypted and can be encrypted further based on your implementation. :-)