# Cannot create a session after the response has been committed - PrettyFaces MultiPageMessagesSupport on Glassfish4

Tags: jsf-2, prettyfaces, glassfish-4

I have a Java EE app where I use JSF2 + PrettyFaces + EBJ3 + Glassfish

I just recently updated to Glassfish4 which is the default Server implementation for Java EE 7 and I started getting issues with PrettyFaces.

I have configured on my faces-config.xml:

```
<lifecycle>
  <phase-listener>com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.event.MultiPageMessagesSupport</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

to enable for Faces Messages to be passed around correctly and displayed on screen.

But since I upgraded from Glassfish3 to 4 I started getting this issue:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has
been committed
...

```
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.util.FacesMessagesUtils.saveMessages(FacesMe
ssagesUtils.java:56)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.event.MultiPageMessagesSupport.afterPhase(Mu
ltiPageMessagesSupport.java:66)
```

If I remove the listener from faces-config.xml none of the Faces messages are displayed on screen.

I am using PrettyFaces to have nice well formatted URLs to enhance SEO on my site. I wish I couldn't have to replace it or refactor my app to not use it since I already mapped a lot of the navigation flow using it. Does somebody know a better option for this scenario?
I really appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I'm no expert in PrettyFaces but tweaking the [state saving method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8471551/1530938) may help to workaround the issue. GF4 ships with JSF2.2, which has not been officially released, so this is a bug(or some incompatibility) in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend to use `MultiPageMessagesSupport` if you are deploying to a "modern" container with JSF 2.2 support. The `MultiPageMessagesSupport` phase listener has been developed for JSF 1.x. JSF 2.x added support for persisting messages across redirects. Just execute this code before redirecting:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
```

Comment: Well then I would have to place this line of code before every JSF navigation case returning "pretty:" or "pretty:something"?

Comment: Yes, or you could write a PhaseListener that calls this method on every request after RESTORE_VIEW or something like that. To be honest, I'm not sure what the common practice for this is. I for myself have a Messages helper class I use to queue message which always sets this flag after adding a message to the queue.