# PrettyFaces, transient view and named path parameters give a warning

Tags: jsf-2.2, prettyfaces

I have a weird problem with PrettyFaces:

When combining a transient view (`<f:view transient="true" />`), named parameters in my `pretty-config.xml` (`<pattern value="/document/#{id}" />`), I get the following warning in my `<h:messages />`:

```
@ViewScoped beans are not supported on stateless views
```

The warning disappears as soon as I remove the `#{id}` from my pattern. I think that, somehow, PrettyFaces stores some state in the viewscope when using named parameters and JSF does not like it inside a transient view.

Is it a bug?

Comment: Not sure about PrettyFaces part, but stateless views are, uhm, stateless. So any view scoped bean tied to it would behave exactly like a request scoped bean. Simply because there's no means of a view state to store the view scoped bean in. I'm not sure why you're still attempting to use a view scoped bean on it. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14890995

Comment: The problem is that the only bean used in the view is a `@Model`... In fact I'm using the same bean for 2 different transient views (serving `/documents` and `/documents/#{id}`). Only the last one exhibits the problem... So I really think PrettyFaces tries to store things in the viewscope when named parameters are used.

Comment: I tested further... even if I don't use any bean at all in my view, I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to come from a bug in the JSF implementation.

See those 2 links:

- https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/issues/208
- https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3939