# Primefaces fileUpload and session timout

Tags: jsf, servlets, file-upload, primefaces, session-timeout

Could a session timeout happen if there are several very big files are uploaded? Imagine I upload one 5 GByte big file and a short session timeout is set. Could the session timeout occur during streaming the file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it can. The [servlet specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/servlet-3_1-final.pdf) does nowhere forbid that a session could be destroyed during an active request. You'll thus risk a [`ViewExpiredException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored) when such an upload arrives at bean.

If this is your concern, you've several options:

1. Let the upload form asynchronously poll to the server at intervals to keep the session alive. You can in EL use `#{session.maxInactiveInterval}` to obtain the current timeout in seconds.

   ```
   <p:fileUpload ... />
   <p:poll interval="#{session.maxInactiveInterval - 10}" async="true" />
   ```

   The 10 seconds difference is just to prevent that it arrives a few seconds too late because the page itself may also take some time to load all the HTML and to initialize the poll. You can if necessary conditionally start/render the poll on start of upload.

   ---
2. Let the "onstart" event of upload increase the session timeout to a certain limit (hour?) and let the "oncomplete" event of upload put it back.

   ```
   <p:fileUpload ... onstart="increaseTimeout()" oncomplete="resetTimeout()" />
   <p:remoteCommand name="increaseTimeout" listener="#{bean.increaseTimeout}" />
   <p:remoteCommand name="resetTimeout" listener="#{bean.resetTimeout}" />
   ```

   You can in bean use [`ExternalContext#setSessionMaxInactiveInterval()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#setSessionMaxInactiveInterval-int-) to set the desired session timeout in seconds.

   ---
3. Use a [stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890995/what-is-the-usefulness-of-statelessness-in-jsf) JSF form. The view will never expire, regardless of how the HTTP session behaves.

   ```
   <f:view transient="true">
       ...
   </f:view>
   ```

   Note: any view scoped beans tied to such a view will behave like request scoped ones. To avoid confusion, replace the annotations if necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use option 2 because the `p:fileUpload` is no more visible in my case when the upload is done. It is inside a dialog which will be closed and the upload is initiated via javascript call.

Comment: +1 for the mention of the stateless JSF form! :D didn't know that until now. in what jsf release will it be available?

Comment: @Fritz: It's officially available since JSF 2.2, but in Mojarra it's been backported to 2.1.19. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3642919

Comment: The `p:fileUpload` `fileUploadListener` specified method is called for each file. So probably each call of this method resets the session time counter? Right? If a very big file is uploaded the requests of the file upload servlet does not reset the timeout counter? Right or not?

Comment: When using `multiple="true"`, the files are sent simultaneously, so `onstart` is called once. The files are processed individually, so `oncomplete` is called for each file. This would make option 2 a poor choice and option 1 a better choice. Nonetheless, option 1 is in any case most reliable as you never know beforehand how long an upload would take. Not sure what you mean with "file upload servlet" in context of this question.

Comment: Yes option 1 sounds better. "file upload servlet" was wrong. It was a mistake when I thought about the FileUploadFilter. So the session counter is reset on each oncomplete, right?

Comment: When using option 2, yes.

Comment: Option 1 is not working. The session expires (HttpSessionListener.sessionDestroyed is executed). Maybe I should post my solution in a new question?

Comment: I fixed the poll example, I overlooked the async bit.

Comment: I added a `p:poll` listener method which is called, but the session expires anyway.

Comment: I added also a `Thread.sleep()` inside the upload handling method to exceed the session.

Comment: There was a `p:idleMonitor` somewhere in the code. After removing it, it works now. Unfortunately my "session expired" dialog is no more displayed when the session expired.

Comment: I think the `idleMonitor` has to be reset when the session time is extended.