# Exception trying to poll with PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I am getting an exception trying to poll with PrimeFaces.  I'm using solution #1 from [Primefaces fileUpload and session timout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780287/primefaces-fileupload-and-session-timout).

> javax.faces.FacesException: class java.lang.Long is not supported as "interval" for p:poll

```html
<p:fileUpload id="fileUploadControl" oncomplete="PF('xmlUploadDialog').hide()"
              listener="#{xmlUploadBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced"
              allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xml|zip)$/" update=":mainForm:scriptTableId"
              multiple="true" />
<p:poll interval="#{session.maxInactiveInterval - 10}" async="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In PrimeFaces 10, the attribute `interval` does not take a `Long` it can take an `Integer` or `Duration`.

See the code:

```java
        Object interval = poll.getInterval();

        int convertedInterval;
        if (interval instanceof Integer) {
            convertedInterval = (Integer) interval;
        }
        else if (interval instanceof Duration) {
            convertedInterval = (int) ((Duration) interval).getSeconds();
        }
        else if (interval instanceof String) {
            try {
                convertedInterval = Integer.parseInt((String) interval);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new FacesException(interval + " is not a valid integer for \"interval\" for p:poll", e);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new FacesException(interval.getClass() + " is not supported as \"interval\" for p:poll");
        }
```

Support for `Long` was added to PrimeFaces 11.

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/7914