# DefaultFaceletsStateManagementHelper.SERIALIZED_VIEW

Tags: jsf-2

Bean is not marked to be in session scope still I notice the below object in session:

```
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.DefaultFaceletsStateManagementHelper.SERIALIZED_VIEW
```

It is consuming around 6000 bytes.

Any suggestion on why this is getting created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the view state of the JSF views which have been requested in the current session. This is normal if the state saving method is set to `server` (as by default) instead of `client`.

#### See also:

- [Why JSF saves the state of UI components on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474316/why-does-jsf-need-to-save-the-state-of-ui-components-on-the-server-side)