# Partial State Saving Feature in JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2

Can someone please explain the partial state saving feature in JSF ? I have worked with JSF 1.2 and this feature didn't exist there . I think it is new to JSF 2.0 ? What benefit do we get by partial state saving over regular state saving ?

Comment: This is also answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474316/why-does-jsf-need-to-save-the-state-of-ui-components-on-the-server-side/5475564#5475564. Basically, it saves memory and improves thus performance.

Comment: @BalusC is this a property that can be configured on per component level or on a application level ?

Comment: Per application or view. Not per component.

Answer (score 2):

It provides to less memory usage by saving just modification on bean. Default is true, you can set it on conf like below;

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```