# Too many active sessions

Tags: jsf, session, jboss, cdi

I am using JSF 2 on JBoss 6. I made a sample application which use JSF as the View, EJB for logic and JPA for Persistence. The bean in JSF has RequestScoped. EJB is stateless:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Long HDi</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <c:forEach var="tweet" items="#{tweets.getAll}">
            <p>
                #{tweet.content}<br />
            </p>
        </c:forEach>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Bean:

```
@Named("tweets")
@RequestScoped
public class Tweets implements Serializable {
    @EJB
    private TweetServiceLocal tweetService;
    private List<Tweet> tweets;

    public List<Tweet> getGetAll() {
        return tweetService.findAllSortedByTimeDesc();
    }
}
```

EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class TweetService implements TweetServiceLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "LongHDi-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Tweet create(final String content, final Date postTime) throws ContentTooLargeException {
        if (content.length() > 480)
            throw new ContentTooLargeException("Content must have less than 480 charaters!");
        else {
            try {
                Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
                tweet.setContent(content);
                tweet.setPostTime(postTime);
                em.persist(tweet);
                return tweet;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public java.util.List<Tweet> findAllSortedByTimeDesc() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Tweet.findAllSortedByTimeDesc").getResultList();
    }

}
```

When I send a few hundreds requests to it, the JBoss 6 server throws this exception:

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 500 - JBWEB000209: Session creation failed due to too many active sessions

JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000066: Exception report

JBWEB000068: message JBWEB000209: Session creation failed due to too many active sessions

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000145: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

JBWEB000070: exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: JBWEB000209: Session creation failed due to too many active sessions
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
JBWEB000071: root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB000209: Session creation failed due to too many active sessions
    org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.createSession(StandardManager.java:297)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2651)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2357)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:790)
    com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getSession(ExternalContextImpl.java:157)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.getSession(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:494)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:400)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
```

My question is: why does the server create too many session? I used RequestScope and Stateless bean, how come they end up in session? What can I do to overcome this situation? If I use only servlet and JSP, when there are too many requests, the server is slowed down but at least it is not halted like this.

Comment: What does `use only servlet and JSP` mean ?

Comment: it means "if I use Servlet and JSP only instead of using JSF". There's nothing unclear, isn't there?

Comment: Post this in JBoss forums they could evaluate it better.

Comment: What are you using to send the requests?
 
If you're using a tool it needs to return the JSESSIONID cookie with every subsequent request.

from: https://community.jboss.org/thread/228632

Comment: @KarlKildén I posted the question you quoted

Comment: Sorry about that. I find it weird nobody else had this issue. Good luck

Comment: They key here is com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.getSession(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:494) - why JSF calls getSession with true. My JSF sources don't have this call (2.0.6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *why does the server create too many session?*

Because you sent a few hundred requests to it and the server is apparently configured to create max X sessions.

---

> *I used RequestScope and Stateless bean, how come they end up in session?*

They didn't. The JSF view state did. When setting JSF state saving method to `server`, which is the default setting, then JSF will store the view state in HTTP session.

---

> *What can I do to overcome this situation?*

Set JSF state saving method to `client` by this context parameter in `web.xml`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This way the JSF view state will in serialized form be stored in the `javax.faces.ViewState` hidden input field of the JSF form instead of in the HTTP session.

Or, when using Mojarra 2.1.19 or newer, just turn off JSF state saving on a per-view basis by setting `transient` attribute of the `<f:view>` to `true`.

```
<f:view transient="true">
```

*(you can wrap `<f:view>` around `<h:head>`/`<h:body>`; this is also what JSF is implicitly doing — it represents the `UIViewRoot` component)*

#### See also:

- [Why JSF saves the state of UI components on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474316/why-does-jsf-need-to-save-the-state-of-ui-components-on-the-server-side/5475564#5475564)